# Can't redirect user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to redirect user to different url after certain event has fired but I keep receiving this error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Illuminate\Routing\Redirector given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php on line 72
```

I have event listener in EventServiceProvider:

```
\Slides\Saml2\Events\SignedIn::class => [
   SamlLoginListener::class.'@handle',
]
```

and then in SamlLoginListener:

```
public function handle(SignedIn $event)
    {
        $messageId = $event->auth->getLastMessageId();
        // your own code preventing reuse of a $messageId to stop replay attacks
        $samlUser = $event->auth->getSaml2User();

        $user_data = [
            'id' => $samlUser->getUserId(),
            'attributes' => $samlUser->getAttributes(),
            'assertion' => $samlUser->getRawSamlAssertion()
        ];

        AuthController::saml_login($user_data);
    }
```

Then In the AuthController::saml_login I tried all of these but the response was allways the same error:

```
            return redirect()->away($frontend_url, 302, [
                'X-SSO-AUTH-TOKENS' => json_encode($data),
            ]);

//

            $response = new RedirectResponse($redirect_url, 302, [
                'X-SSO-AUTH-TOKENS' => json_encode($data),
            ]);
            return $response;
//
            
            return redirect($redirect_url, 302, [
                'X-SSO-AUTH-TOKENS' => json_encode($data),
            ]);
```

I decided to try it again by just returning 'ok' but still received the same error. I tried clearing the cache - no result.

Here is the full error trace: https://pastebin.com/4eZYni0w

Comment: Can you post the full trace? It should be in your logs in `storage/logs`

Comment: Updated the question with the link for it.

Comment: If you take that out, what happens? The error trace doesn't ever show it getting out of the vendor folder.

Comment: take out what? I tried just return 'ok' and received the same error

Comment: Though now that I think about it, I'm not sure you can return a response on an event. Events run kind of to the side of the process. In any case, I don't think the problem is with this code, because the stack trace doesn't reference any of the non-vendor files

Comment: hmm, how can I redirect user then?

Comment: The redirect user would be in the main flow, or in an Authenticate middleware

Comment: https://github.com/24Slides/laravel-saml2 mentions SSO-friendly links, with a `returnTo` in the URL. From some of the issues in GitHub, that's what you need

Comment: it just returns url

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem is in the error message. Your error is saying that the redirect helper method expects a string, but you're passing an object.

Not sure what version of Laravel you're using but in Laravel, Redirect responses are instances of the Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse class and contain the proper headers needed to redirect the user to another URL.

you can try:

`return redirect('/frontend_route');`

Redirect to named route:

```
return redirect()->route('frontend_route');
```

If this your route has parameters like in your case, here's what to do:

```
return redirect()->route('frontend_route', ['X-SSO-AUTH-TOKENS' => json_encode($data)]);
```

Hope this helps.

source: [Redirects in Laravel 8](https://%27X-SSO-AUTH-TOKENS%27%20=%3E%20json_encode($data))

Comment: I am using Laravel 9. $frontend_url is actually string: "https://example.com/"

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this and it worked:

```
header("Location: " . $redirect_url); 
header("X-SSO-AUTH-TOKENS: " . json_encode($data)); 
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `redirect()` function (in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`) was returning a `RedirectResponse` when **I provided a valid URL** and a `Redirector` object when I called it with `null`.

```
/** @var RedirectResponse $redirectResponse */
$redirectResponse = redirect('http://example.org');

/** @var Redirector $redirector */
$redirector = redirect(null);
```

The solution was to validate my input and redirect back to the previous page when I could not proceed.